# Salesforce Flow ListDataType invalid response

Tags: visual-workflow

I have been trying to get an api call to work properly in salesforce flow and have been having issues getting the responses to come through properly.

I make a post request with an api definition shown below:

```
"/scan/copado/findings": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "scan"
        ],
        "summary": "Get the findings associated with a scan",
        "description": "",
        "operationId": "getFindings",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "header",
            "name": "x-access-token",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Salesforce org id",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/pdfScanId"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/findingObj"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "api_key": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }

"findingObj": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "scanId": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "array of scan IDs",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "severity": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "screenshots": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "remediationguidance": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "isnew": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "status": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "traces": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {}
          }
        },
        "_id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "orgId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "line": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "col": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "filename": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "issuetype": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "founddate": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "updateddate": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "issue": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "assigned": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hash": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "history": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {}
          }
        },
        "comments": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This api call returns a value similar to below:

```
{
    scanId: [
      60a482a16b933f2b148f59d1,
      60db502ec0fd5f0960dc7da4
    ],
    severity: 'low',
    screenshots: [],
    remediationguidance: [
      'One way to defend against this risk is to validate identities upon change in email addresses.',
      'Go to Security Controls > Session Settings and select Require identity verification for email address changes'
    ],
    isnew: true,
    status: 'Active',
    traces: [],
    _id: 60a482fe6b933f2b148f59d8,
    orgId: 60a46843f9af6d396cbbe91b,
    codesnippets: 'E-mail confirmation is not enabled for email changes.',
    exploits: 'E-mail confirmation is not enabled for email changes.',
    line: 0,
    col: 0,
    filename: 'NA',
    issuetype: 'SFDC_IDENTITY_CONFIRMATION',
    founddate: 2021-05-19T03:16:14.727Z,
    updateddate: 2021-05-19T03:16:14.727Z,
    severityid: 3,
    issue: 'Identity Confirmation Disabled',
    description: 'This setting indicates if a user’s identity is confirmed when changing their email address, instead of requiring a relogin. It is important to verify the identity of a user as a change can be made erronously. ',
    assigned: null,
    hash: 'ffc27ef4a5e7a6c4503b17fc58efdee2d60a6498',
    history: [],
    comments: [],
    __v: 0
  }
```

When I get the response in the salesforce flow I get the following error:

```
Invalid response parameter type: ListDataType{ServiceComponent{name=, variant=null, version='(-1.-1.-1)', description=null, id=1Xl5e000000TN24}, elementDataType=ObjectDataType{ServiceComponent{name=findingObj, variant=null, version='(-1.-1.-1)', description=null, id=1Xo5e000000TNC4}, properties=[scanId,severity,screenshots,remediationguidance,isnew,status,traces,_id,orgId,line,col,filename,issuetype,founddate,updateddate,issue,description,assigned,hash,history,comments]}} for parameter: 200 and invokable action: S4Digitsec::S4.getFindings
```

This api call works using Talend and Postman, but cant seem to find a way to get the response to come through properly in salesforce flow. Has anyone run into this issue previously?

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this issue out of the blue, my callouts at some point worked then Salesforce started rejecting the response type. My guess is that when Salesforce made its recent changes to ExternalServices. It seems like Salesforce got really specific in how it expects responses to be returned

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/05/learn-moar-with-summer-21-external-services-enhancements

Here is what I did.

1. Instead of creating the output variables and assigning them myself in the flow, I let salesforce decide

[image: Uncheck 'Manually Assign', if doing so]

2. I then used the 'Output' from the action in my decision nodes or wherever else you will need to reference the output

[image: Salesforce gives you the Output automatically as a resource]

Hope this helps!